# Unable to get desired output in CSV

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to get the list of groups and members in sharepoint site using sharepoint powershell. The powershell shows the correct output but when exported as CSV, the Roles & Groups show as ****"System Collection Generic List 1[System String]**

The code is as under `Get-SPOSiteGroup -site https://uctechgroup.sharepoint.com/ | Select Title, Roles, Users | Export-Csv "C:\123.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

I checked onto the web and it does mention to use join function but I am not sure how it needs to be done.

The snippet of the CSV is as attached:

[CSV Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoMqO.png)

Could anyone please help me with the same

Tried using separate scripts but still the same output

Comment: the issue is that you are trying to output an array with nested arrays into a flat table. CSV is not well suited for this, like JSON or XML are, so you'll need to flatten the nested arrays to make this come out nicely. For Example `Get-SPOSiteGroup -site https://uctechgroup.sharepoint.com/ | Select Title, @{l='Roles';e={$_.Roles -join ', '}}, @{l='Users';e={$_.Users -join ', '}} | Export-Csv "C:\123.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Thanks MadTechnician... That really helped me get started..

Answer (score 0):

Just adding @TheMadTechnician's comment here as an answer to close this thread.

```
Get-SPOSiteGroup -site https://uctechgroup.sharepoint.com/ | Select Title, @{l='Roles';e={$_.Roles -join ', '}}, @{l='Users';e={$_.Users -join ', '}} | Export-Csv "C:\123.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```